# c++ vektor always gives 0

Tags: c++, vector

my first.h:

```
class skaiciavimas
{
public:
    vector<int> vekto[2];
    skaiciavimas();
    ~skaiciavimas();
....
```

my first.cpp

```
    #include "skaiciavimas.h"

skaiciavimas::skaiciavimas()
{   int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    vekto[i].resize(3);
}
void skaiciavimas::showst(vector<int> st,int i)
{   
    vekto[i].at(0)=st.at(0);
    vekto[i].at(1)=st.at(1);
    vekto[i].at(2)=st.at(2);
    cout<<vekto[1].at(0)<<vekto[0].at(0)<<endl;

}
void skaiciavimas::tikrinimas ()
{
    cout<<vekto[1].at(0)<<vekto[0].at(0)<<endl;// gives always 0,0
....
```

there is second class from where i call shwst function
second.cpp:

```
vandenynas::vandenynas()
{
    vektorV.resize(3);
}
void vandenynas::duomenys (int i, int a, int a0) 
{
        switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            vektorV.at(0)=a-a0;
            break;
        case 1:
            vektorV.at(1)=a-a0;
            break;
        default:
            vektorV.at(2)=a-a0;
            break;

    }
 sk.showst(vektorV,0);
}
```

the tikrinimas function i call from my main:

```
sk.tikrinimas();
```

why this line

```
cout<<vekto[1].at(0)<<vekto[0].at(0)<<endl;
```

alvays gives me 00, how to correct that to get the rigt numbers wich were assign in showst

P.S sk is my class (first sk;)

there is called duomenys and tikrinimas :

```
vandenynas vand;
skaiciavimas sk;
int main() 
{
    int i,a,a0,t;
    int j=1;

    while (j<3)
    {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
          cout<<"enter "<<kas<<kint(i)<<" kordinates"<<endl;
          cout<<kint(i)<<"0 = ";
          cin>>a0;
          cout<<kint(i)<<" = ";
          cin>>a;
          cout<<endl;
          if (j==1)
              vand.duomenys(i,a,a0);            
         }
     j++;
    }
    sk.tikrinimas();
...
```

Comment: It's very hard to read code when you have no idea what the function names mean.

Comment: It's bad practice to name variables/function names in any other language than english. The code is very unreadable.

Comment: Where is `vektorV` declared..?

Comment: As a substitue, consider posting the program verbatim, so we at least don't have to guess about the C++ too

Comment: Where are you calling duomenys?

Comment: Just to get this right, you do call the function to initialize the vectors before you show them? And you do not do anything between those two calls that will change the vectors (like changing scope)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg can you take more datails where is my mistake?

Comment: Ok, `duomnys` is called in `main` to set up the vectors, can you show that call? And is `tikrinimas` also called in `main`?

Comment: @thax: "It's bad practice to name variables/function names in any other language than english. The code is very unreadable." I've never seen such an ignorant comment! The non-English-speaking programmers of the world are forced to acquire some knowledge of English just to use the tools of their profession. Now you are telling them to forget their native language entirely? Edgar, I would never use Lithuanian variable names in my own code, but I will fight to the death for your right to do so!

Comment: @TonyK thnx, but i partially agree with thax, another time i will try to translate them, to make code more "readable" just i thougth that there is no diffrence between lithuanian an english names in understanding code.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg yes...
added the part off main

Comment: --- dumb comment removed by author ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      cin>>a0;
```

You read the input into local variables, but never call `sk.showst` with those values.  It shouldn't be surprising that it's members are still whatever the defaults are.